# How to account for punctuation and uppercase while counting the number of occurrences of a string in a sentence

Tags: javascript, string, function, split

I'm writing a function but cannot figure out how to account for upper case letter and punctuation.

My function is :

```
function countWords(word, string) {
    var subStr = string.split(word);
    return subStr.length - 1;
}
```

And it works when I try to test is with wordCount("hey","this is code hey"), but not if I try ("HEY", "this is code hey")

I tried

```
var subStr= string.toUpperCase().split(word)
```

but it will not work with lower case letters anymore.

Comment: call touppercase on both string and word

Comment: @aw04 for example var subStr= string.toUpperCase(string).split(word) ?

Comment: var subStr = string.toUpperCase().split(word.toUpperCase())

Comment: Try ignoreCase. It would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you try like this.

```
function countWords(word, string) {
    word= word.toLowerCase();
    string=string.toLowerCase();
    var subStr = string.split(word);
    return subStr.length - 1;
}
```

So that whatever values we sent it will be converted into lower case then it will split.
Does it makes sense right?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```js
function countWords(word, string) {
    var subStr = string.toLowerCase().split(word.toLowerCase());
    return subStr.length - 1;
}
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#result').html(countWords("HEY","this is code hey"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try sending the parameter to either all upper or lower cases first so that it matches the case of the string you are comparing it to. For example,

```
function countWords(word.toLowerCase, string.toLowerCase)
```

That way the search is evaluated regardless of case.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex with the `i` and `g` modifier (case insensitive/match all) and match, then return the length:

```
function wordCount(search, txt) {
    var regex = new RegExp("\\W" + search + "\\W|\\W" + search, "ig");
  var match = txt.match(regex);
  return match ? match.length : 0;
}

console.log(wordCount("hey","this is code heyHey HEY hey")); // 2
```

If you want to have heyHey as 2 matches, simply remove `|\\W" + search` from the regex